# Get customer group name from customer group ID

Tags: orders, customer-group

I need to use the customer group name in the invoice. Based on `$order` I can get the customer group ID.

```
$customerGroupId = $order->getCustomerGroupId();
```

I tried the following code:

```
$groupname = Mage::getModel(‘customer/customer_group’)->load($customerGroupId);
```

This results in the following error:

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function load() on a non-object
```

How can I get the group name?

Comment: Which Magento Version are you even using?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The object I think you are looking for is `Mage_Customer_Model_Group` so you will need to update your load to use the following.

```
$groupname = Mage::getModel('customer/group')->load($customerGroupId)->getCustomerGroupCode();
```

On another note there is no name on customer groups but instead 'customer_group_code'. With the default data that comes with Magento the codes look as follows.

```
NOT LOGGED IN, General...etc
```

To get the code you can either call `getCustomerGroupCode` or there is a function `getCode` which is simply an alias for the first one.

Comment: That's quick! Can't accept the answer right now (have to wait 10 minutes), but will do so later!