# getCustomerGroupId from order in invoice template

Tags: orders, invoice, customer-group, transactional-mail

I'm trying to put some custom text in an invoice template (a transactional mail). I am doing this by loading a block in the template. In here i want to use some logic to display some text based on GroupId.

**In Invoice_new.html**

```
{{block type='core/template' area='frontend' template='mailcomment/mailcomment.phtml' order=$order}}
```

**In my new file mailcomment.phtml

```
<?php $customergroup = $this->getData('order')->getCustomerGroupId(); 
if ($customergroup==7) 
echo ("Some custom text")?>
```

Unfortuntely this does not work. Can anybody tell me what i am doing wrong?

Comment: $this->getData('order') is given result?

Comment: I used an example for getting the payment method:
    $paymentmethod = $this->getData('order')->getPayment()->getMethodInstance()->getCode();

This works just fine.

Comment: And this info i was trying to use: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/19015/get-customer-group-name-from-customer-group-id

Comment: are you tried this thing $paymentmethod = $this->getData('order')->getPayment()->getMethodInstance()->getCode();  on   mailcomment/mailcomment.phtml file?

Comment: Yes but that gets the paymentmethod in the variabel $customergroup. I would like this variable to contain the customergroupid.

Comment: Here is something that looks loke this:
http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/19015/get-customer-group-name-from-customer-group-id

They use: $groupname = Mage::getModel('customer/group')->load($customerGroupId)->getCustomerGroupCode();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems OK, so leave it as it is:

```
{{block type='core/template' area='frontend' template='mailcomment/mailcomment.phtml' order=$order}}
```

Try changing your phtml file:

```
<?php if ($this->getOrder()->getCustomerGroupId() == 7): ?>
    <?php echo $this->__('Yes') ?>
<?php else: ?>
    <?php echo $this->__('No') ?>
<?php endif ?>
```